# Ubuntu 22.04.3 - VMware Kernel Module Updater

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, vmware-player

Ran into the GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 12.3.0 was not found.
I have seen this issue before and have resolved it, however when I run the commands below I still receive the request for GCC. Is the solution to upgrade my current version of Ubuntu or is this something VMware needs to look at?

GCC version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

OS    - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Gnome - 42.9 / Wayland

System version:

```
uname -a
Linux craig-devops 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How I installed VMware bundle

```
sudo apt install gcc build-essential -y
chmod +x VMware-Player-Full-17.5.0-22583795.x86_64.bundle
sudo bash VMware-Player-Full-17.5.0-22583795.x86_64.bundle
```

Comment: Upgraded to 23.04 - Linux 6.5.0-14-generic - Issue resolved after the upgrade, VMWare Player runs without the GCC error

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading your version of Ubuntu to 23.10 as 23.04 will go EOL in about 13 days on Jan 25.

Comment: One other note here, gcc version 12.3.0 should have been installed into Ubuntu 22.04.3, but the system may have been pointing `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc-11`.  That can be easily updated by running `sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Upgraded to 23.04 - Linux 6.5.0-14-generic

Issue resolved after the upgrade, VMWare Player runs without the GCC error

Answer (score 0):

Do not have to upgrade system to use vmware. Just:

```
apt install gcc-12
```

and then as path to gcc provide:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-12
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

Install the version of gcc that was used to compile the kernel you're using:

```
sudo apt install $(cat /proc/version | grep -Po 'gcc-\d+')
```

##### Details

I just ran into a similar problem, except in my case I was installing VirtualBox. It needs to install a kernel module, and it needs to be installed with the same version of gcc that was used to compile the kernel.

Because I have the HWE kernel installed, it was compiled with a newer kernel than the one installed by default in Ubuntu. In my case, the kernel was compiled with gcc-12:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.5.0-17-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-043) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #17~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jan 16 14:32:32 UTC 2
```