# Issues after ubuntu 22.04.3 upgraded to linux 6.5.0-14

Tags: kernel, ssh, vmware, gcc

I have 2 issues since being upgraded to linux 6.5.0-14 from 6.2.0-39:

#1:
I'm unable to compile the modules needed for vmware workstation player 17. Version 17.0.2 build-21581411.  At first it could not find gcc-12.  Following the recommendations from another post I installed gcc-12 and linked it. By doing the following:
sudo apt install gcc-12

```
sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc
```

After doing that it started compiling but failed. Here's a snippet from the vm log file:

```
2024-01-16T21:14:35.424Z In(05) host-4433 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/Makefile:2037: /tmp/modconfig-XOkG7f/vmnet-only] Error 2
2024-01-16T21:14:35.424Z In(05) host-4433 make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
2024-01-16T21:14:35.424Z In(05) host-4433 make: *** [Makefile:117: vmnet.ko] Error 2
2024-01-16T21:14:35.424Z In(05) host-4433 Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
2024-01-16T21:14:35.424Z In(05) host-4433
```

#2
The other issue that I have is that I can no longer login using ssh.  When I try I get this message:
"ssh: connect to host nero port 22: invalid argument".  I don't have these issue when booting up using linux 6.2.0-39.

Comment: You should not manually create symlinks (or change anything else) in `/usr/bin`. That directory (as well as `/usr/lib`, `/usr/share`, etc) is under control of the package management system. Changes there will almost certainly break things. If you need overrides, do so in the `/usr/local/*` hierarchy. You can break the very same things there, but not damage the state of your system that is managed by APT.

Comment: You didn't specify if you're using the Server or Desktop release of Ubuntu 22.04, but switching to the GA kernel stack (5.15) might be any easy option (*rather than HWE which upgrades to kernels used by newer releases; 6.2 from 23.04, 6.5 from 23.10*)  Your install media sets the default (some using GA, others HWE; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: @zwets I believe that OP here followed a comment that I had made on the other post of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499824/ubuntu-22-04-3-vmware-kernel-module-updater#comment2627853_1499824.  But there is a way to set it up so that the `update-alternatives` for gcc is set by following https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version/26518#26518.  I did also recently perform an installation of VMware Player 17.0.2 and Kernel 6.5.0-14-generic and it worked fine by modifying the softlink to gcc before I added mine to the update-alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, that snippet of the log doesn't show as to why it failed.  We will probably need to see more of it.  Also, what are you trying to SSH to?  A message like Invalid Argument is due to usually IP translation.  Not sure why that is, but off the top of my head is that in 6.5.0-14-generic the NIC may not be working properly.  You haven't given us enough info for us to really give you an answer.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, I checked the `update-alternatives` route as well, as I was expecting the switch to be available there as a 'built-in', but weirdly it isn't. Maybe time for my first question on AU: How do I switch between gcc versions? :) Anyway, my fierce defence of APT's autocracy over `/usr/*` still stands :p and `ln -sfT /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/local/bin/gcc` is there for us mere mortals to override it.

Comment: @Terrance I am using the desktop version.  I don't ssh a lot, but I do use scp to copy file between my systems at home.  I'm not sure how much of the vmware log file to show or if there is a way to upload the file it is around 230 lines. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: @Frank You can use the https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ site to upload an entire log to.  Then all you would have to post is the link to the log.

Comment: @Terrance I hope I'm doing this right.  Here is the Link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/W8pXRpDj9H/

Comment: I have another the system that was upgraded    uname -a
Linux frank-dev 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  It's gcc and g++ are still at 11.40  gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0  g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Comment: Yep, you did it right.  Looks like it is failing on an incompatibility of the driver for vmnet-only bridge:  `/tmp/modconfig-ghwCI1/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1413:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘tcp_gso_segment’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]` which I have seen the same message with an older NIC driver with the r8168 8.049.01 driver and the 6.5.0-14-generic kernel.  You might want to try to download another VMWare Player that might be updated.  I am not at home right now to check what version I downloaded, but I know that my test install passed.

Comment: @Terrance I don't use the wired nic.  I use the wireless.  Can I disable the wired nic?  I believe it is on the motherboard.

Comment: I put that as an example in my comment where I saw that same type of failure.  The `vmnet-only` is a virtual driver installed by VMWare that bridges whatever NIC you are using into the VM.

Comment: @Terrance This probably explains my  ssh issue as well.

Comment: @Frank I just VPNd into my home network for the time being.  I downloaded the VMWare Player version 17.5.0.  That is what I am using and it installed without an issue with the new Kernel and the change of `gcc` to point to the `gcc-12`.  I didn't test 17.0.2, but it wouldn't surprise me where that version is not compatible with the 6.5.0-14-generic Kernel.

Comment: I know I mentioned earlier in another comment about VMWare Player 17.0.2, but that's what I get when I am not sitting in front of my system.  Sorry about that.  I did indeed install the 17.5.0 version.

Comment: @Terrance I had success installing version 17.5.0.  Thank you.  I don't know to post the answer is that something you do or do I?

Comment: Let me write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VMWare Player 17+ appears to be calling for gcc 12.3.0.  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS should already have `gcc-12` installed, but if it doesn't, you can install it.  I would use the `--reinstall` flag to install it just in case.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-12
```

You can then check if `gcc` is part of the `update-alternatives` (or symbolic links) by running `sudo update-alternatives --list gcc`, but I have not seen `gcc` recently be in the `update-alternatives`.  Since it is a symbolic link you can simply update the link to point to `gcc-12` or point to the binary of `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12`.

```
sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc
```

or

```
sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc
```

You are more than welcome to add it to the `update-alternatives` by following through the answer here [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version/26518#26518).  Or, I have added the lines below to add it (I am only going to to do the `gcc` and not the `cc` or `g++` lines, etc):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-12 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 30
```

The `10`, `20` and `30` are the priority numbers, and the higher the number the higher the priority.

You can now check the `update-alternatives` for `gcc` by running the following:

```
$ update-alternatives --list gcc
/usr/bin/gcc-11
/usr/bin/gcc-12
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
```

Then to config `gcc` to a different version run the follwing:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
There are 3 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12   30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-11                    10        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gcc-12                    20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12   30        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

It appears as though VMWare Player 17.0.2 is incompatible with the `6.5.0-14-generic` kernel.  In the [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/W8pXRpDj9H) that you posted in lines 210 - 213 is the following error:

```
2024-01-17T11:02:29.957Z In(05) host-3229 /tmp/modconfig-ghwCI1/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1413:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘tcp_gso_segment’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
2024-01-17T11:02:29.957Z In(05) host-3229  1413 |    segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, 0);
2024-01-17T11:02:29.957Z In(05) host-3229       |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-01-17T11:02:29.957Z In(05) host-3229       |           tcp_gso_segment
```

which is showing that the driver for the `vmnet-only` bridge is failing to build and that error is calling the `segs` that isn't compatible with the new Kernel. The version `17.5.0` has been updated for that driver and is compatible with Kernel 6.5.0-14-generic.

You can download the VMWare Player 17.5.0 from https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/downloads/details?downloadGroup=WKST-PLAYER-1750&productId=1377&rPId=111473 and install it.

```
chmod +x VMware-Player-Full-17.5.0-22583795.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Player-Full-17.5.0-22583795.x86_64.bundle
```

Hope this helps!