# vmmon and vmnet are not installing in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (kernel 6.5.0-21-generic)

Tags: command-line, 22.04, virtualization, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am tring to install Vmware Workstation 17 on my device. I installed the `.bundle` file got from the official website. Installed `gcc gcc-11 gcc-12 build-essentials` via `apt`.Then I ran the command `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` but found this error.[The very first output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwUJ9.png)
So I did the replacement of codes from  [mkubecek's Github repo](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules). It did not work. This is `VMware Player 17.5.1 build-23298084`. What else I can do??
Here is the log from the command

```
ahanaf@Dell-Latitude-E6440:~$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[sudo] password for ahanaf: 
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                done
   Virtual machine monitor                                     done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-21-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-21-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/procfs.o
/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumAndCopyToUser+0x2d: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-8hCRDz/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                    failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                     done
   VM communication interface socket family                    done
   Virtual ethernet                                           failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                done
Unable to start services
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /usr/bin/gcc` and or the output of `ls -al /etc/alternatives/gcc`?  Add the output to your question and not in comments down here.  Maybe this answer might help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500314/issues-after-ubuntu-22-04-3-upgraded-to-linux-6-5-0-14/1500516#1500516

Comment: Thank you buddy for your reply. This issue was security. Due to secure-boot my BIOS was preventing the kernel to modify now all goes as it should.
thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you were able to find the solution!  :)  Feel free to write up your own answer below.  :)